# How can I access to Start Menu path?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to get files from `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and its subfolders.

I'm trying to get them like this:

```
string path = @"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\";
string[] lnks = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.lnk", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`
```

But it giving me an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Access denied to the path : 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs'
```

And those are what I tried to get access to that path;

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" /> to the app.manifest
```

`File.GetAccessControl(path);` in codes

Starting Visual Studio as Admin

None of them worked. So how can I get those files from that path?

Comment: Can't you change the path and put files in some other folder. The best way is to give the security rights on the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with that folder is the presence of a [ReparsePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365503(v=vs.85).aspx) folder with a name localized for your culture (for example in my machine I have folder named "Programmi" (the reparse point) and the real folder named "Programs")

Directory.GetFiles seems to fail when trying to read a ReparsePoint folder but you can avoid it with code like this

```
string path = @"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\";
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach (string s in dirs)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(s);
    if (!di.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)) 
    {
        string[] lnks = Directory.GetFiles(s, "*.lnk", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

string allUsers=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ALLUSERSPROFILE")+ "\Start Menu\Programs";